# Flutter how to encrypt my api parameters to AES algorithm with CBC Mode

Tags: flutter, dart

I am using some API in which they accept encrypted data only.

They said I need to send them like this

```
Trandata will contain below parameters encrypted with AES algorithm with CBC Mode,
PKCS5Padding with initialization vector value PGKEYENCDECIVSPC under Resource Key
```

This is the data I need to encrypt

```
[{"amt":"12.00","action":"1","password":"q@a68O$27@JLkcK","id":"IPAYlCR6qZF7q6w"
,"currencycode":"048","trackId":"12345656789","udf1":"","udf2":"udf2text","udf3"
:"udf3text","udf4":"udf4text","udf5":"udf5text",
"responseURL":"http://www.companyName.com/testPayment","errorURL":"http://www.companyName.com/testPayment"}]
```

After encrpy result with look like this

```
B38EAB17207C551A0DD86571A9E64486258D57B8926F2BF0A4F91A4FF3506A
E3EB829ABAEB12F9014D2C5BA66EB5808B947F3FADE1840FC16A2A704DBA33AEC2CA499D1B45F227
CCD18FA5E788CBA35D3E236F82AB6A4375E1BBAF710919E3A10A5B0F975A737D150FD54313641A46
A108DF8F6A49367F48197DED9C0BA0299F20D4959FD84EFC227D7D7E29AF6293DE55320F5A5E7173
E15AD114F0388D892AE8B310F3A2EFE42E864403763BC3B18684AD11D5F9828C8FB10558CAE2D6AF
1B52C556E53ED2961829F62F4589E305B53983CAAAD168ECC75EA938CCD4F7EC3471C0A8A2B14079
1C9135FA7AB1C21FCA35295583AF3E19CB4CFAEE27F175628566BE0D41BFA06CD9CC5779E637F22E
743CC9CF0AAC6C3877C7CA3BBCCF76706FB056E43689C8035F684C6B3DC00CCE03D1945B2DA0F6F1
1E7EC1EC09E4B6F731791EF28F28E34DAD0FB6E2958E482BE24A635B2779AE741FA0029A41FFD9DD
7E4E121307C65A567F5164B57D5EAED252681A065A1BE703076C29A1E636C75B646011DFE5A0A63C
CC164A3C1186B8FBD93E845D89B2A1DCCD6A366CAF77BFF7EDA627824A600B668216F17B1BFE8465
7C405DF95AD21957A9D1193D6D80BAE63E1296BEAAB26096EB78C557109554E438DDA997A9D85D15
B3EC680EBA5EBCDCB558A2D0DF9460B79BE88D063342CD6B0B3C26C3965962F25A9BD42CBFC2843E
F044C54153A8DD4FDB7D162270CDEA617A43E99BAA036FDACD7F6DC59E264BBD59
```

Now I am stuck how can I do this encryption is there plugin or how it will done ?

I try to use encrypt pluign also like this

```
import 'package:encrypt/encrypt.dart' as ec;

    final key = ec.Key.fromUtf8('PGKEYENCDECIVSPC');
    final iv = ec.IV.fromLength(16);
    final plainText = "${[{"amt":"12.00","action":"1","password":"q@a68O27@JLkcK","id":"IPAYlCR6qZF7q6w"
      ,"currencycode":"048","trackId":"12345656789","udf1":"","udf2":"udf2text","udf3"
          :"udf3text","udf4":"udf4text","udf5":"udf5text",
      "responseURL":"http://www.companyName.com/testPayment","errorURL":"http://www.companyName.com/testPayment"}]}";

    print(plainText);
    final encrypter = ec.Encrypter(ec.AES(key, mode: ec.AESMode.cbc, padding: null));
    final encrypted = encrypter.encrypt(plainText, iv: iv);
    print('enc');
    print(' enc  ${encrypted.base64}');
    print(' enc  ${encrypted.base16}');
```

but its not showing correct encrypt data because when I add `PKCS5Padding` in padding as a string  its showing error `No algorithm registered of type Padding with name: PKCS5Padding`

Comment: https://pub.dev/packages/encrypt Will this help?

Comment: @MayurDhurpate yup also try that but issue in padding comes I update my question also now how I use that plugin